# UserProfile.location" must be a "Location" instance

Tags: django, forms, foreign-keys, instance

I am still experiencing some problems with understanding forms and relationships between model-forms.
I am getting an error:
UserProfile.location" must be a "Location" instance.

I've set location in models to blank=True, null=True and required=False in forms.py.
And I dont really know at this point what to do with that.

How I can fix that problem?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Location(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    #county = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    #province = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey("Location", null=True, blank=True)

    website = models.URLField("Site", null=True, blank=True)
    accepted_rules = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    accepted_rules_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    #points_count = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    #posts_count = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    #comments_count = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
```

Forms:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import Form
from django.forms.models import ModelForm
from accounts.models import UserProfile, Location
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserCreationForm(forms.Form):

    username = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    email = forms.EmailField()
    #password_repeat = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

    def clean_username(self):

        try:
            # iexact = case-insensitive match / important for validation
            User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
            print "User does already exist"
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return self.cleaned_data['username'] 
    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError("User already exists")



def clean_email(self):

    if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=self.cleaned_data['email']):
        print u'Adres email jest już używany.' 
        raise forms.ValidationError('Adres email jest już używany.') 
    else:
        return self.cleaned_data['email']

def save(self):
    user  = User.objects.create(username = self.cleaned_data['username'], email = self.cleaned_data['email'],)

    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])
    return user


class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    website = forms.URLField(label="website", required=False)
    location = forms.ChoiceField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        include = ['website', 'location']
        exclude = ('user', 'type', 'accepted_rules')
```

Views

```
contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from accounts.forms import UserCreationForm, UserProfileForm



def index(request):
    return TemplateResponse(request, "base.html")

@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    user_profile = UserProfileForm()

    if request.method == "POST":

        form = UserCreationForm(prefix='user', data=request.POST or None)
        user_profile = UserProfileForm(prefix='profile', data= request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid() and user_profile.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            profile = user_profile.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()


            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

    return TemplateResponse(request, 'accounts/register.html', {
                             'form':form,
                             'user_profile':user_profile ,
                             }
                            )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here.

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    website = forms.URLField(label="website", required=False)
    location = forms.ChoiceField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        include = ['website', 'location']
        exclude = ('user', 'type', 'accepted_rules')
```

`ModelForm` will generate needed fields for your form. You don't need to define them manually. So you should use something like this.

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        include = ['website', 'location']
        exclude = ('user', 'type', 'accepted_rules')
```

Another thing. There is no `include` option, I think you wanted to use `fields`. But you don't have to use both `fields` and `exclude`, usually you need to use one them. In your case `exclude` is enough. Final result:

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user', 'type', 'accepted_rules')
```

Comment: That kinda solved my problem but there's an another bug I occur all the time. If I leave fields from second form empty I get an error in user creation form that "this field is required" even though that its filled in correctly